# Drag and Drop table cell contents

Tags: jquery, html

I have a Dynamic table here. Table data includes one span also. How can drag and drop that span anywhere among table's cells?

```
<table id="#our_table">
    <tr>
        <th>head1</th>
        <th>head1</th>
        <th>head1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span id="event"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you may want to read this : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Comment: thanks for your support  GCyrillus, mean like event calender :)

Comment: sort of, you can, from a table, easily do something like this : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/HdpAI

Answer (score 9):

Or you just use drag drop html5 with this simple code ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/egt4U/))

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.event').on("dragstart", function (event) {
              var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
              dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
            });
        $('table td').on("dragenter dragover drop", function (event) {  
           event.preventDefault();
           if (event.type === 'drop') {
              var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text',$(this).attr('id'));
              de=$('#'+data).detach();
              de.appendTo($(this)); 
           };
       });
})
</script>
```

with this code you must also assign an id to your span tag
in this other [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/2RuBh/) you can  see the effect with two span tags.
In this case if there is a span in the cell the drop event does not work

Answer (score 3):

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/B93w9/

```
$(function() {
    $( "#our_table span" ).draggable();
    $( "#our_table td" ).droppable();
});
```

and rename your table's id `<table id="our_table">`

Comment: this method is good but not working in my case. because my span is appending dynamically

Comment: @user3598780 : dynamically how ?

Comment: like event calender event

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you could also try the jQuery UI library. The span should be a draggable http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ and the cell a droppable http://jqueryui.com/droppable/