# How can I drag-and-drop cell contents within a table with dynamically added rows and cells?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm having difficulty with drag-and-drop with a dynamically generated table.  The interface renders a grid of table rows and cells based on user selections.

What I'd like to do is enable the user to drag the contents of one cell, a div or span, into another cell.

This conversation from nearly 6 years ago comes close to what I want to do. But it fails to handle the case where a table has rows that are dynamically added.
[Drag and Drop table cell contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472505/drag-and-drop-table-cell-contents)

```
$(function() {
  $('.event').on("dragstart", function(event) {
    var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
    dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
  });
  $('table td').on("dragenter dragover drop", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.type === 'drop') {
      var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
      de = $('#' + data).detach();
      de.appendTo($(this));
    };
  });
  $('#addRow').on('click', function() {
    $('#targetTable > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
  });
});
```

This example, based on that code, demonstrates my problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/Stormjack/osvu6mea/11/

You can successfully drag-and-drop the blue block to any cell in the first two rows. But add a new row with the "Add Row" button, and you can't drop that block into any new row. You can still move the draggable span to different cells in the first two rows. But it fails to drag into the new row.

How can I overcome this limitation?  I'm happy to use any combination of HTML5 or JavaScript or jQuery or another client-side library. Thanks for your help.

---

Here is my solution, based on saintvixalien's help.

```
$(function() {
 initDragAndDrop();
 $('#addRow').on('click', function() {
    $('#targetTable > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
    clearDragAndDrop();
    initDragAndDrop();
 });
});

function clearDragAndDrop() {
 $('.event').off();
 $('table td').off('dragenter dragover drop');
}

function initDragAndDrop() {
 $('.event').on('dragstart', function(event) {
    var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
    dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
 });
 $('table td').on('dragenter dragover drop', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.type === 'drop') {
      var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
      de = $('#' + data).detach();
      de.appendTo($(this));
    }
 });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Stormjack/osvu6mea/15/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, when you added the `"dragenter dragover drop"` event listener, there were only 2 rows that means that for each new row added, you'll have to add the event listeners to it.

**CAUTION**: If you run the event listening process every time a new row is added, you will end up with the old rows having 2 or more event listeners which is not performant and can cause issues.

A solution would be to add new rows with a class of `new-row` and then you add the event listeners to the `new-row`s and then remove the `new-row` ids.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rcf4qp85/

```js
  $(function() {
    $('.event').on("dragstart", function(event) {
      var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
      dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
    });
    initnewrows();
    $('#addRow').on('click', function() {
      $('#targetTable > tbody:last-child').append('<tr class="new-row"><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>'); initnewrows();
    });
  });

function initnewrows() {
    $('table tr.new-row td').on("dragenter dragover drop", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (event.type === 'drop') {
        var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
        de = $('#' + data).detach();
        de.appendTo($(this));
      }
    });
   $('table tr.new-row').removeClass('new-row');
}
```

You'll also have to add the class `new-row` to the initially present `trs`.

```html
  <table id="targetTable" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr class="new-row">
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="new-row">
        <td><span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">Move Me</span></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="new-row">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <p><button id='addRow'>Add Row</button></p>
  <p>
  You can successfully drag the "Move Me" block to any cell in the first two rows.<br/>But add a new row with the "Add Row" button, and you can't drop that block into any new row.
  </p>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rcf4qp85/

Comment: Thank you, saintvixalien! Your explanation helped tremendously. The main problem that I missed was the timing of adding event listeners. Thanks so much!